# (com.itextpdf.text.ExceptionConverter) java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 256

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I've been using `itext` to extract text from pdf, it works fine but certain pdfs arise some problems. It sounds very weird because I can
normally open it with acrobat reader. I've read a little about tif pdf or pdf that contais some tif pic or file and it seems like don't work with this method, but this pdf
seem not contains any of these files and I'm just interested in text. 
Here is my method to extrac text: it work well to some pdfs that are similar to the other that doesn't work.

```
public String getPdfContent(String pdfPath) {
    try {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
        PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
        TextExtractionStrategy strategy;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        SimpleTextExtractionStrategy stes = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
        stes.getResultantText();
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            try {
                strategy = parser.processContent(i, stes);
                sb.append(strategy.getResultantText());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                UTGeraLog.gravaErro(ex);
            }
        }
        reader.close();
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        UTGeraLog.gravaErro(ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

the catch block get:

> "com.itextpdf.text.ExceptionConverter) java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 256"

and I still can not solve this problem ='(. Maybe Special Characters ? out of utf range ? it use ASCII code ?
Ps.: I'm using `itextpdf-5.5.7.jar`

Comment: I don't know how PdfReader works, but did you mean `i = 0; i < reader.getNumberOfPages()` or am I assuming it starts at 0?

Comment: It seems that there is no page 0, it's why I'm using i = 1 ; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); ..